# What is the difference between using var and not when declaring a variable?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = 123;
b = 456;
console.log(window.a, window.b); // 123, 456
delete window.a; // true
delete window.b; // false
console.log(window.a, window.b); // 123, undefined
```

Why can not delete the global variable if var is not used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.

When you use

```
b = 456;
```

the interpreter turns this into

```
window.b = 456;
```

that is, an assignment to a property on the `window` object. But `a` is different - although it also *happens* to be assigned to a property on the `window` object, it is also now a part of the `LexicalEnvironment` (rather than just being a property of an object) and as such is not deletable via `delete`.

```js
var a = 123;
b = 456;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'a'))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'b'))
```

See how the variable declared with `var` has `configurable: false`, while the implicit `b` assignment has `configurable: true`.